# How Int32 datatype is directly assigned?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Int32 i = new Int32();
i = 10;
```

Here I is struct data type and we are assigning a value to it directly where

```
struct myst
{
}

myst mySt = new myst();
myst = 10;
```

Here I need a property to assign so the question is how `Int32` is able to assign a value to struct object directly?

Comment: `10` is an `Int32`, so you can assign it to a variable of type `Int32`. If you had a `myst`, you could assign it directly to `mySt` for the same effect, `myst` and `Int32` aren’t the same type, though. (Also, I’m pretty sure that `Int32` isn’t a struct. It’s a value type, though.) `new Int32()` is irrelevant.

Comment: 'Int32' is a struct, struct is a value type and we can use 'Int32 i = new Int32(); i=10;'  i just wanted to know how it is achieving like that and ans is implicit operator

Comment: Maybe the confusion is that you think `10` isn’t an `Int32`? It is. `int` and `System.Int32` are exactly the same type.

Comment: `int` is an alias for `Int32`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand you correctly (and i have no idea if i do). To assign *implicitly* to a *Custom Type*, you will need to implement an *Implicit Operator*

[implicit operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)

> The implicit keyword is used to declare an implicit user-defined type
>   conversion operator. Use it to enable implicit conversions between a
>   user-defined type and another type, if the conversion is guaranteed
>   not to cause a loss of data.

**Example**

```
struct FunkyStruct 
{

   public FunkyStruct(int d) { val = d; }
   public int val;
   // ...other members

   // User-defined conversion from Digit to double
   public static implicit operator int(FunkyStruct d)
   {
      return d.val;
   }
   //  User-defined conversion from double to Digit
   public static implicit operator FunkyStruct(int d)
   {
      return new FunkyStruct(d);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void Main()
{
   FunkyStruct s;
   s = 10;
   Console.WriteLine(s.val);
}
```

**Update**

> Console.WriteLine(s) and it should print 10 just like int how can I
>   achieve this

It already does

[**Full Demo Here**](http://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/86Mv45)

Comment: Hi Michael this is a bit out of the topic `myst` cant inherit ValueType as it is class but I'm getting ToString() how this is possible? please check the link once [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684035/struct-tostring-method-is-redirecting-to-abstract-class-valuetype/)

Comment: they metioned : in general we can't but these are some special cases within the language is this true?

Comment: Hi @avinash this might be worthy of another question, and a bit more information on what you are trying to do, and what you are having trouble with

Comment: I did ask a question please check the link  u will get all the info thanks

Comment: @avinash yes in some special cases, i.e *.Net* can work on different rules than we can (using *.net*). do you need to inherit from something?

Comment: no, I'm trying just learning .net as deep as possible and u know where I check this

Comment: @avinash the answer you were given is valid, there are many examples of where *.Net* the compiler can do things that we as *.Net* user cant do. Think if *.Net* as a friendly Dictator/General it needs to enforce rules but it can break them itself... You have found 1 such case

Answer (score 1):

myst is not Int32 . One thing you can do here is , create Int32 variable inside struct and assign value for that.

```
 struct myst
    {
       public Int32 a { get; set; }
    }


 static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
            myst mySt = new myst();
            mySt.a = 10;
        }
```