# struct tostring() method is redirecting to abstract class ValueType

Tags: c#, .net

`Int32 i = new Int32();
i.ToString();`

The ToString method redirecting `struct Int32` and `.ToString()` has a `override` 
so I want to check where it is overriding so I created a `struct`

```
struct myStruct {} 
myStruct my= new myStruct();
my.ToString();
```

when I redirecting I mean press f12 it moved to `public abstract class ValueType`
But we can't inherit class into a struct

So the question is how I'm getting `my.ToString();` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503568/system-valuetype-understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FROM MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)

> All value types are derived implicitly from the **System.ValueType**.

also worth noting that ([MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

> The **ValueType.ToString** method overrides the **Object.ToString** method and provides the default implementation of the **ToString** method for value types. (Value types are types defined by the struct keyword in C#

`Struct` and primitive types inherit from `ValueType` as per language design. So it is within the language that's why we can call the `ToString()` on it as the `ValueType` is a class and eventually inherits from `Object` from which every type inherits in C#.

if for instance we [look at the Int type in the c# source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs), we see it's a struct but we can call the methods that available on the `Object` class for the same reason.

We can always look in to the source code of these Base class libraries. [See the code for ValueType.cs here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,93)

Comment: The ValueType.ToString method overrides the Object.ToString as the ValueType is abstract class how is it able to do it

Comment: @avinash abstract class can have methods in it see: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,93

Comment: `myStruct` cant inherit ValueType as it is class but I'm getting `ToString()` how this is possible

Comment: It is inheriting that's cooked within the language

Comment: @avinash in general we can't but these are some special cases within the language

Answer (score 2):

Because it overrides the `Object.ToString` method.

**ValueType overrides the virtual methods from Object with more appropriate implementations for value types.**

> **MSDN**
>
> The `ValueType.ToString` method overrides the `Object.ToString` method
>   and provides the default implementation of the `ToString` method for
>   value types. (Value types are types defined by the `struct` keyword in
>   C#, and by the `Structure...End Structure` construct in Visual Basic.)
>   Functionally, however, the implementation is that same as that of
>   `Object.ToString`: the method returns the fully qualified type name.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) MSDN article for more details.

**UPDATE (based OP comment)**

> ValueType is abstract class how is it able to do it

As you are aware that in .NET, everything is object so `Object` is base class for all other class available in framework. Whenever you create new class, there are three methods available for overriding `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString` because that class automatically inherited from `Object`.
Same thing happens in case of `ValueType`.

Comment: The ValueType.ToString method overrides the Object.ToString as the ValueType is abstract class how is it able to do it

Comment: Now it makes sense but `myStruct ` cant inherit  `ValueType` as it is class but I'm getting `ToString()' how this is possible